# JSON Data into Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

im creating javascript Chart using JSON Generated values (im using chart.js). so far i have generated the JSON Object from PHP. now i wanted to assign those values in Chart.

My JSON OBJECT like this

`[{"name:""John","first:""100","second:""300","third:""200"}]`

for that PHP code is

```
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $response = array('name' => $row['username'],
    'first' => $row['first'],
    'second' => $row['second'],
    'third' => $row['third'],
);

    $responses[]=$response;
```

There is no problem with above codes.

and i want to assign those retrieved values in below code. (this is for CHART.JS)

```
var pieData = [
        {
          value: "[here]",// values goes to here
          color:"#F7464A",
          highlight: "#FF5A5E",
          label: name
        },
        {
          value: 50,
          color: "#46BFBD",
          highlight: "#5AD3D1",
          label: "Green"
        },
        {
          value: 100,
          color: "#FDB45C",
          highlight: "#FFC870",
          label: "Yellow"
        },

      ];

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);
```

I tried something like this

```
obj = JSON.parse(values);
value: obj.name, //but this didnt work
color:"#F7464A",
highlight: "#FF5A5E",
label: name
```

even i tried `alert (obj.name);` im getting `Undefined`.

Comment: I assume the json was hand typed for this question? it has a few typos.

Comment: Your javascript at the very bottom also looks a bit... invalid. Like you're missing something.

Comment: Your JSON represents an array, therefore, `obj` is going to contain an array with a single item that is an object. Possibly returning the data incorrectly on the backend? or can there be multiple?

Comment: `console.log(obj)` would show you the exact structure you're working with. you probably want `obj[0].name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `JSON` data is an array of object,  you need to access the its index:

```
obj[0].name
```

but if you think about it, you can just encode that one row directly, if you expect one record.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
json_decode($row);
```

Then your JSON would look like this:

```
{"name:""John","first:""100","second:""300","third:""200"}
```

therfore `obj.name` would work, it would not be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
obj = JSON.parse(values);
value: obj[0].name, 
color:"#F7464A",
highlight: "#FF5A5E",
label: name
```

Comment: @CadeLewis plz accept the answer if it is working for you :) thanks in advance